# Can PHP maintain a persistent session with a server, as a client?

Tags: php, session, client, fopen

Say I'm on my home PC with my browser open, I visit a site that uses sessions, as long as I don't close my browser or remain idle for 24 minutes the session will be maintained as I make subsequent HTTP requests to the site.

However on my server running PHP, if I use fopen() or file_get_contents() to request a page from that same site, does that site create a session for the 'user' that is my server?  Is there a way to keep the connection open so the session is maintained for subsequent fopen() requests?

Can I do this by passing the session id in the request headers on the subsequent request?  ie I set the headers including the session id, pass the headers to a context_stream_create(), and then pass the context with the next fopen() request?  Can this be done for POST requests (which is what I really need to do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any app which can speak HTTP language have the capability to save the cookie and therefore save the state in HTTP.

The answer to your questions is YES. You can do anything you want with just using the right protocol ( GET/POST ) and sending proper headers ( Host, User-Agent, ... )
But you have an alternate solution, i think this class will help : [PHP Browser Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browser)

Comment: That looks like it could work for what I'm doing but does it include a way to send custom headers in each request?

Comment: @Joey You could also use curl. You can send any headers you want, including the session id cookie.

Comment: The Browser class doesn't have a method for adding arbitrary headers, but as it uses CURL, you can do it with a few lines code.